# Setting up selenium to work with internet explorer

Tags: python, selenium, internet-explorer, selenium-iedriver, iedriverserver

I have created a python script that I can execute and does exactly what I want under the Google Chromedriver. However, to make sure that my executable can work on all PCs, I would like to have my script work with the internet explorer driver but I am having issues. I have attached a sample test code I am trying to run below along with the error message I am receiving.

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Ie()
driver.get("google.com")
```

And the error code I am receiving is:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Unexpected error 
launching Internet Explorer. IELaunchURL() returned HRESULT 800700C1 ('%1 is 
not a valid Win32 application.') for URL 'http://localhost:58689/'
```

Any ideas? I have installed the IEdriver and placed it on my desktop along with the test.py file I mentioned above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to consider a couple of facts here:

1. While working with `Selenium 3.4.0` downloading the IEdriver and placing it on your desktop along with the test.py file may not suffice. Ideally we should be passing the absolute path of the `IEDriverServer.exe` within our code block to reduce manual configuration and be able to work with multiple versions of `IEDriverServer.exe` as per your requirement as follows:

   ```
   driver=webdriver.Ie(r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\IEDriverServer.exe')
   ```
2. The error you are seeing exactly points me to the mismatch within `IEDriverServer.exe` version, installed `IE Browser` version and your underlying  `OS` version. Here either you have configured `64 bit IEDriverServer.exe` to work with `32 bit IE browser` or  you have configured `32 bit IEDriverServer.exe` to work with `64 bit IE browser`. You can find some discussions on the error **`HRESULT 800700C1 ('%1 is 
   not a valid Win32 application.')`** [**here**](https://forums.asp.net/t/983377.aspx?%20is%20not%20a%20valid%20Win32%20application%20Exception%20from%20HRESULT%200x800700C1%20) and [**here**](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ee96f19f-2f45-4f62-8ecd-dccf5857b29d/get-runtime-error-800700c1-1-is-not-a-valid-win32-application?forum=vcgeneral).
3. If you are using IE 11 you may consider to set up your Test Environment as per the specification mentioned [**here**](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver).