# Selenium performance with InternetExplorerDriver and IE11

Tags: selenium, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, selenium-iedriver, iedriverserver

I am facing a very slow response when running my scripts on IE11. Sometimes, I get `FocusWindowsClosed`, `ElementIsNotClickable`. I have changed the zoom settings for all zones, created feature `BFCACHE` for *IE* in feature control, added capabilities into my code but nothing works for me. If anyone has any idea why I am facing this issue. Do i need to downgrade window or IE versions? I have also downloaded the same version of selenium client server with same IEDriver which is (3.8.0).

Comment: The exceptions you mention are not caused by IE running slow. They might be caused by selenium running too fast. Please post the code that throws the exceptions.

Comment: The selenium and IEDriver version you using are too old. You could refer to DebanjanB's answer to upgrade your selenium and IEDriver version and check the other points in the answer. If it still doesn't solve your issue, it could be better if you provide a [minimal code sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to reproduce the issue. So that we can test and see how to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start with, [Selenium v3.8.0](http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=3.8/) of *2017-11-30* is more then 2 years older. Even the error trace logs would be difficult to debug. So as per best practices you may like to:

- First of all, the fact that *...64-bit IEDriverServer executable populate the input fields with the character sequence very slowly as compared to 32-bit IEDriverServer executable....* is a known issue.

> You can find a detailed discussion in [IEDriverServer sends text very slowly using Selenium to the search field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54217788/iedriverserver-sends-text-very-slowly-using-selenium-to-the-search-field/54218594#54218594)

- Ensure the [Internet Explorer Protective mode setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49850465/internet-explorer-protective-mode-setting-and-zoom-levels/49851282#49851282) are properly configured.
- Ensure the [Zoom level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49788994/how-to-ignore-zoom-setting/49789100#49789100) is properly configured.
- Ensure [ignoreProtectedModeSettings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48020561/internet-explorer-not-launched-using-selenium-even-though-ignoreprotect-mode-set/48020684#48020684) is properly confugured.
- Ensure [setting up selenium to work with internet explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45571476/setting-up-selenium-to-work-with-internet-explorer/45582602#45582602).
- Ensure [FEATURE_BFCACHE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51600120/how-does-the-registry-entry-hkey-local-machine-feature-bfcache-for-internete/51929196#51929196) is properly confugured.
- Upgrade *Selenium* to  current levels [Version 3.141.59](https://selenium.dev/downloads/).
- Upgrade *IEDriverServer* to  latest [IEDriverServer v3.150.1](http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=3.150/) level.

  > **Note**: As per *best practices* as *Selenium Client* and *InternetExplorerDriver* are released in sync and you must try to use both the binaries from the same **major** release.
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- Execute your `@Test`.
- Always invoke `driver.quit()` within `tearDown(){}` method to close & destroy the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully.

---

### tl;dr

A couple of references:

- [Internet Explorer 11 getting stuck randomly while executing tests through IEDriverServer and Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51977120/internet-explorer-11-getting-stuck-randomly-while-executing-tests-through-iedriv/51983888#51983888)
- [HTTP Status: '500' -> incorrect JSON status mapping for 'timeout' (408 expected) while clicking element with IEDriverServer Selenium and Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53723400/http-status-500-incorrect-json-status-mapping-for-timeout-408-expected/53725397#53725397)

Comment: still after adding everthing i am facing that issue running slow. Any suggestions?

Comment: @AlexAlex Updated the answer with more information regarding _running slow_ issue. Let me know if you have any questions.